# Migrating Laravel to another server

Tags: php, laravel, server

I have a problem with migrating laravel to another server, 
I currently have laravel + redis of which I have some functions in the site cache on redis, the problem is the following, 
the site works in the other server, but the command schedule:run does not work in cronjob, I tried to run it manually, but it gives me back "No scheduled commands are ready to run" when on the first server runs correctly, the second server is ubuntu 16.04, there is something special to do when changing server? attached I enclose the kernel.php

The old server has Centos 7 Running MariaDB 10.1, PHP 7.2 and NGINX

The new has Ubuntu 16.04 Running MariaDB 10.1, PHP 7.2 and NGINX

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        '\App\Console\Commands\CacheSideBar',
        '\App\Console\Commands\DailyReset',
        '\App\Console\Commands\WeeklyReset',
        '\App\Console\Commands\MonthlyReset',
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
         //$schedule->command('cache:sidebar');
        $schedule->command('reset:daily')
                 ->daily()
                 ->withoutOverlapping();

        $schedule->command('reset:weekly')
                 ->weeklyOn(1, '00:00')
                 ->withoutOverlapping();                 

        $schedule->command('reset:monthly')
                 ->monthlyOn(1, '00:00')
                 ->withoutOverlapping();

        $schedule->command('cache:sidebar')
                 ->everyTenMinutes()
                 ->withoutOverlapping();


    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have crontab installed on the server. You need to register the your cronjobs using crontab on the server.

N.B if you don't have it installed see https://tecadmin.net/install-crontab-in-linux/ or https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/linux-crontab/

steps:

1) ssh into the server

2) type `crontab -e` in the cli

3) add the cronjobs by typing `* * * * * cd /var/www/yoursite && php artisan schedule:run` . then save.

4) Now the `php artisan schedule:run` will be run every minute, checking if there is any due commands to run.

N.B for you to run it manually, try changing the 'daily' to 'everyMinute' like so:

```
$schedule->command('reset:daily')
                 ->everyMinute()
                 ->withoutOverlapping();
```

It will get triggered. 
Hope it helps :)